# OpenCV Contours?

Tags: c++, video, opencv, variable-assignment

I keep getting an error with this part of the code

```
&contours = ((contours.h_next) -> h_next);
contours.h_next = ((contours.h_next) -> h_next) -> h_next;
```

The error states "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am not able to post the complete code right now sorry

Oh and contours isn't a pointer to a sequence - its an actual sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&contours` is a pointer value. you can't assign to a value. e.g. you can't assign to `42`.

Cheers & hth.,